# Making C# compatible interface for C++/CLI managed type

Tags: c#, .net, interface, c++-cli

I have some native C/C++ functions for which I'm creating managed wrappers in C++/CLI (Visual Studio 2015).

In particular, one of my managed types looks like this:

```cpp
public ref class MyClass abstract : public IMyClass
{
public:
    virtual void SomeMethod(ID id);
}
```

The type **ID** is defined as:

```cpp
typedef unsigned long ID;
```

Due to unit testing purposes, I would like to create compatible interfaces to my wrapper types on a different C# assembly that I want to keep separate from the C++/CLI world, so I made this interface:

```cs
public interface IMyClass
{
    void SomeMethod(uint id);
}
```

When I try to compile the managed C++/CLI assembly I'm getting and error saying that I should provide a suitable implementation for "**void SomeMethod(unsigned int)**".

I used the type **uint** on my interface because according to this [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-framework-equivalents-to-cpp-native-types-cpp-cli), an **unsigned long** is converted to the managed type **System.UInt32** (uint), but it seems like (the opposite) using **unsigned long** to implement a **uint** is not possible.

Have any of you had the same problem before? Do you know how to fix this?
Is it possible to tell the C++/CLI compiler that my unsigned long should be treated as a uint type?

I can't change the ID definition as it is part of the native library and is used extensively by other functions.

Comment: It is not a compatible interface.  You probably got the namespace and type name correct, but that is not good enough in .NET.  Type identity also includes the assembly it came from.  A strong DLL Hell countermeasure.  Your test program must use the exact same interface type, add a reference to the assembly that defines it if you haven't done so already.

Comment: You seem to be using C#, but just as a hint: `UInt32` is *not* CLS compliant. Other .NET languages may not understand it.

Comment: I understand that and I know it isn't a problem with the assemblies, but with how the compiler translates between native/managed types and vice-versa. What puzzles me is that an "unsigned long" gets compiled to a UInt32 but when the compiler sees an interface with UInt32 but implemented as an "unsigned long", they are incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When in doubt, be explicit.

I recommend that you use [`System::UInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) everywhere: when you define the interface type, and when you implement it. This will eliminate any subtle mismatches between the definition & the implementation.

In C++ land, `int` and `long` are distinct types, even if they are the same size. When implementing an interface, the parameter type must match exactly, and it appears that the subtle difference between a 32-bit `int` and a 32-bit `long` makes a difference.

Comment: As I stated before... I cannot change the definition of ID (unsigned long). I can only change the definition of the C# interface I'm trying to make.

In other words... it seems like there is NO WAY I can make a compatible interface for that type (ID) in .NET?

Comment: Use `System::UInt32` for all of the .Net related code (the interface definition & implementation). If it's a 32-bit `unsigned long` elsewhere, that's fine, as it will trivially convert when you call the method, but it must match *exactly* when you implement the interface.

Comment: Thank you @david-yaw, that worked fine. Unfortunately my codebase was too big to make these changes all over the place. Had to go a different route but I'm accepting this answer.